# SQLの副問い合わせのALLについての質問です。

Tags: sql

SQLの副問い合わせのALLを勉強しているのですが、以下の文は何が違いがわかりません。
違いが分からず、検証してみたところ出力の違いを出すことはできました。
以下の文で条件の「<」「>」のうち「>」は出力が一緒なのですが、「<」だと出力が異なります。

```sql
SELECT * FROM 家計簿 WHERE 入金額 > ALL (SELECT 入金額 FROM 家計簿アーカイブ);
SELECT * FROM 家計簿 WHERE 入金額 > (SELECT MAX(入金額) FROM 家計簿アーカイブ);
```

```sql
SELECT * FROM 家計簿 WHERE 入金額 < ALL (SELECT 入金額 FROM 家計簿アーカイブ);
SELECT * FROM 家計簿 WHERE 入金額 < (SELECT MAX(入金額) FROM 家計簿アーカイブ);
```

実際に使ったテーブルは以下のように設定しました。

```sql
DROP TABLE 家計簿 IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE 家計簿(日付 DATE, 費目 VARCHAR(20), メモ VARCHAR(100), 入金額 INTEGER, 出金額 INTEGER);
INSERT INTO 家計簿 VALUES('2013-01-10','給料','12月の給料',300000,0);
INSERT INTO 家計簿 VALUES('2013-02-10','給料','1月の給料',280000,0);
INSERT INTO 家計簿 VALUES('2013-02-18','水道光熱費','1月の電気代',0,7560);
INSERT INTO 家計簿 VALUES('2013-03-10','給料','2月の給料',290000,0);
INSERT INTO 家計簿 VALUES('2013-04-10','給料','3月の給料',250000,0);

DROP TABLE 家計簿アーカイブ IF EXISTS;
CREATE TABLE 家計簿アーカイブ(日付 DATE, 費目 VARCHAR(20), メモ VARCHAR(100), 入金額 INTEGER, 出金額 INTEGER); 
INSERT INTO 家計簿アーカイブ VALUES('2012-12-10','給料','11月の給料',280000,0);
INSERT INTO 家計簿アーカイブ VALUES('2012-12-25','居住費','1月の家賃支払い',0,80000);
INSERT INTO 家計簿アーカイブ VALUES('2013-01-10','給料','12月の給料',280000,0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ALL句](http://www.sql-reference.com/select/subquery_all.html)は全ての条件に一致する条件なので、下記のように言い換えることができます。
つまり項番3と項番5、および項番4と項番6のSQLがそれぞれ等価であり、質問文の項番3と項番4は意味が異なります。

1. `... hoge > ALL(SELECT fuga ...`

- hogeがすべてのfugaより大きい

2. `... hoge > (SELECT MAX(fuga) ...`

- hogeがすべてのfugaより大きい(← 集計したfugaの最大値より大きい)

3. `... hoge < ALL(SELECT fuga ...`

- hogeがすべてのfugaより小さい

4. `... hoge < (SELECT MAX(fuga) ...`

- hogeが**いずれかの**fugaより小さい(← 集計したfugaの最大値より小さい)

5. `... hoge < (SELECT MIN(fuga) ...`

- hogeがすべてのfugaより小さい(← 集計したfugaの**最小値**より小さい)

6. `... hoge < ANY(SELECT fuga ...`

- hogeが**いずれかの**fugaより小さい